# How to redirect all 404 pages to the same URL in nginx?

Tags: nginx, http-status-code-404, redirect

I have setup a 404 page in nginx `error_page 404 /404.php;`

So that if I go to `website.com/some-bad-url` I see the content form `404.php`

My question is how to have `website.com/some-bad-url` redirect to `404.php` directly form nginx and have the browser show the `404.php`page directly ?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `error_page` directive will normally perform an internal redirect. If you specify a scheme and a server name, it will perform an external redirect, but obviously can only use 3xx response codes.

For example:

```
error_page 404 $scheme://$host/404.php;
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#error_page) for details.